# How popular article module is working?

Tags: joomla, module

`/modules/mod_articles_popular/tmpl/default.php`

Can somebody explain me, how this working?
I do not understand how these `$item->link` and `$item->title` get correct information?
Where is MySQL query? Is it global variables? If yes, where they are described?

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, like most modules `/tmpl/default.php` is included on the last line the module entry point file i.e. `mod_articles_popular.php`

In that file `helper.php` is included first followed by

```
$list = modArticlesPopularHelper::getList($params);
```

As you can see this calls the `getList()` method of the helper class which performs the task of retrieving the `$list` of articles.

It (`modArticlesPopularHelper`) in turn loads the `ContentModel` and sets the state of the `$model` based on the default app params and the modules settings.

The it asks the model for the actual items required with the line `$items = $model->getItems()`.

After that it loops through the items returned by the model and creates a `link` value for each article prior to returning it to the module.

As a result `$list` is filled with each of the article items which are pulled out individually in the `foreach` loop in `/tmpl/default.php` file.

Comment: thanks cppl :) , but if I want to get information from another table, for example #__content2. where I can change that? or it is impossible?

Comment: @EdvaPtr - If you want to get information from another table, you will have to write the query yourself. Do not change the core route.php file.

Comment: write where? and I do not understand, how to assign this new query with abstract class modArticlesPopularHelper? or create another class? Or I am totally wrong? ;/

Comment: hello, sorry for delay. I still needed answers to understand it fully.
thank you in advance

Comment: @Lodder , cppl  are you still with me?

Comment: @EdvaPtr - hearing you loud and clear. I personally like to write all queries in a file such as helper.php and include it in default.php

Comment: ok, and what about:
"**I do not understand, how to assign this new query with abstract class modArticlesPopularHelper? or create another class?**"
I am asking, because I did some changes in `#__content_rating` and now I am able to get information from this table, but I do not now know how to create a link to article (now shows only article title, but it not link to this article).
@cppl , maybe you have ideas? you are Joomla master :)